# Determine from which location an application was being started

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, process, shortcut

Is there any possibility to determine how a c# application was being started?

In my case I want to check if this application (wpf) is being started by a shortcut located in a specific folder.

So, there are two ways to open my application

- using direct shortcut
- starting another application which is like an update manager to keep my application up to date. After checking, it starts my application with Process.Start()

And I want to ensure that the application is only able to be started with the update manager.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: Require it to take an argument that is some key that only your UpdateManager knows.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick you could use is to check the parent's PID, and then get some of the parent's process information.

If the parent's process name is something like "explorer.exe" then the application was started from the shortcut or directly by double-clicking it on explorer.

Otherwise, it was started from another application: it could be your updater application, it could also be another application with the same name as your updater application...

This means you have to re-think how deep you want to go for such a solution, and how deep do you want security control. You could pass arguments from your updater to your main application, or implement some inter-process communication with token exchanges... it is impossible to make a 100% secure system.

As someone commented above, this seems like a XY problem... or maybe not. Maybe it is just a security concern. It's recommended to revise what exactly are you aiming for this software.

In case you need sample code for retrieving process information in .NET (by using System.Management), then just give a try to the code listed below. All you have to do is to place it in a console application project named 'Updater', and correctly set the path to your main application in the code.

If you play a little bit with this example by starting and closing **YourApplication.exe** in different situations, then you should be able to see an output like this:

```
Parent process 'Updater.exe' [PID=5472]
Parent process 'explorer.exe' [PID=12052]
```

The code below was tested on VS2017 .Net 4.6.1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = "YourApplication.exe" // path to your application
        });

        while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("YourApplication").FirstOrDefault();  // your application's process name
            if (process == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Process is not running...");
                continue;
            }
            ProcessManager pm = ProcessManager.FromLocalMachine();
            var processProperties = pm.GetProcessProperties(process.Id);
            int parentProcessId = Convert.ToInt32(processProperties[EProcessProperty.ParentProcessId]);

            try
            {
                var parentProcessProperties = pm.GetProcessProperties(parentProcessId);
                string parentProcessName = parentProcessProperties[EProcessProperty.Name].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine($"Parent process '{parentProcessName ?? "Unknown"}' [PID={parentProcessId}]");
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
            }
            catch { Console.WriteLine("Parent process information not found."); }
        }
    }
}

public class ProcessConnection
{
    internal ManagementScope ManagementScope { get; }

    internal ProcessConnection(string machineName, string user = null, string password = null, string domain = null)
    {
        ManagementScope = new ManagementScope
        {
            Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + machineName + @"\root\CIMV2"),
            Options = new ConnectionOptions
            {
                Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default,
                EnablePrivileges = true,
                Username = user == null ? null : (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(domain) ? user : $"{domain}\\{user}"),
                Password = user == null ? null : password,
            },
        };
        ManagementScope.Connect();
    }
}

public class ProcessManager
{
    public static ProcessManager FromLocalMachine() => new ProcessManager()
    {
        Machine = Environment.MachineName,
    };

    public static ProcessManager FromRemoteMachine(string machine, string user = null, string password = null, string domain = null) => new ProcessManager()
    {
        Machine = machine,
        User = user,
        Password = password,
        Domain = domain,
    };

    private ProcessManager() { }

    public string Machine { get; private set; }
    public string User { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public string Domain { get; private set; }

    private ProcessConnection Connection { get; set; }
    private ManagementScope ManagementScope => Connection == null ? (Connection = new ProcessConnection(Machine, User, Password, Domain)).ManagementScope : Connection.ManagementScope;

    public EProcessStartStatus StartProcess(string processPath)
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass($"\\\\{Machine}\\root\\CIMV2", "Win32_Process", null);
        ManagementBaseObject process = mc.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        process["CommandLine"] = processPath;
        ManagementBaseObject createCode = mc.InvokeMethod("Create", process, null);
        string createCodeStr = createCode["ReturnValue"].ToString();
        return (EProcessStartStatus)Convert.ToInt32(createCodeStr);
    }

    public bool KillProcess(string processName)
    {
        try
        {
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{processName}'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) mo.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }

    public bool KillProcess(int processId)
    {
        try
        {
            SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = '{processId}'");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) mo.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }

    public void SetProcessPriority(string processName, EProcessPriority priority)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{processName}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in managementObjectSearcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject methodParams = managementObject.GetMethodParameters("SetPriority");
            methodParams["Priority"] = priority;
            managementObject.InvokeMethod("SetPriority", methodParams, null);
        }
    }

    public string GetProcessOwner(string processName)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{processName}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject methodParams = mo.GetMethodParameters("GetOwner");
            ManagementBaseObject owner = mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", null, null);
            return owner["User"].ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string GetProcessOwnerSID(string processName)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{processName}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject methodParams = mo.GetMethodParameters("GetOwnerSid");
            ManagementBaseObject OwnerSid = mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwnerSid", null, null);
            return OwnerSid["Sid"].ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IList<int> GetRunningProcesses()
    {
        IList<int> processes = new List<int>();
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get()) processes.Add(int.Parse(mo["ProcessId"].ToString()));
        return processes;
    }

    public IDictionary<EProcessProperty, object> GetProcessProperties(int processId)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = '{processId}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);

        Dictionary<EProcessProperty, object> properties = new Dictionary<EProcessProperty, object>();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData pd in mo.Properties)
            {
                if (Enum.TryParse(pd.Name, out EProcessProperty e)) properties[e] = pd.Value;
                else Console.WriteLine(pd.Name + " is not mapped in the properties enumeration.");
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }

    public IDictionary<EProcessProperty, object> GetProcessProperties(string processName)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{processName}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);

        Dictionary<EProcessProperty, object> properties = new Dictionary<EProcessProperty, object>();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
        {
            foreach (PropertyData pd in mo.Properties)
            {
                if (Enum.TryParse(pd.Name, out EProcessProperty e)) properties[e] = pd.Value;
                else Console.WriteLine(pd.Name + " is not mapped in the properties enumeration.");
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }

    public IList<int> GetProcessessFromExecutablePath(string executablePath)
    {
        SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery($"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ExecutablePath = '{executablePath.Replace("\\", "\\\\")}'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(ManagementScope, query);
        return searcher.Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Select(mo => Convert.ToInt32(mo["ProcessId"])).ToList();
    }

}

public enum EProcessPriority : uint
{
    IDLE = 0x40,
    BELOW_NORMAL = 0x4000,
    NORMAL = 0x20,
    ABOVE_NORMAL = 0x8000,
    HIGH_PRIORITY = 0x80,
    REALTIME = 0x100
}

public enum EProcessStartStatus
{
    Success = 0,
    AccessDenied = 2,
    NoPermissions = 3,
    Unknown = 8,
    FileNotFound = 9,
    Invalid = 21,
}

public enum EProcessProperty
{
    Caption,
    CommandLine,
    CreationClassName,
    CreationDate,
    CSCreationClassName,
    CSName,
    Description,
    ExecutablePath,
    ExecutionState,
    Handle,
    HandleCount,
    InstallDate,
    KernelModeTime,
    MaximumWorkingSetSize,
    MinimumWorkingSetSize,
    Name,
    OSCreationClassName,
    OSName,
    OtherOperationCount,
    OtherTransferCount,
    PageFaults,
    PageFileUsage,
    ParentProcessId,
    PeakPageFileUsage,
    PeakVirtualSize,
    PeakWorkingSetSize,
    Priority,
    PrivatePageCount,
    ProcessId,
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage,
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage,
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage,
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage,
    ReadOperationCount,
    ReadTransferCount,
    SessionId,
    Status,
    TerminationDate,
    ThreadCount,
    UserModeTime,
    VirtualSize,
    WindowsVersion,
    WorkingSetSize,
    WriteOperationCount,
    WriteTransferCount,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are only 2 ways of starting your app, the second method should pass a parameter (a GUID?) to Process.Start() - generated by your updater app.

Maybe devise some kind of algorithm that allows the app to start only with the token.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know this is impossible in the way you would like it to be but there's one trick which you can use. Firstly change your WPF application's entry method to get the command line arguments, and ( for example ) use `-u` argument to distinct from where the application was started. Then after `-u` you can pass a `HWND` or a process ID that matches your updater. Of course you have to then check if that application is running and if it's your updater.

*example :*

```
// updated process start
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("your/WPF/application.exe");
psi.Arguments = "-u " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
// fill up rest of the properties you need 
Process.Start(psi);

// wpf application's entry point
void Main(string[] args)
{
    string updaterProcessIdstr = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        if(args[i] == "-u")
        {
            updaterProcessIdstr = args[i + 1];
            i++;
        }
    }
    int pid = int.Parse(updaterProcessIdstr);
    Process updaterProcess = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    // do some validation here
    // send something to stdin and read from stdout 
    // to determine if it was started from that updater.
}
```